# How to exit the script if specific line changed or whatever

Tags: python

Let's say that we do have a script include `10` lines of code.

and the line# `3` include the following `print("hello world")`.

Whatever the print position is inside loop, class or def either outside.

How to terminate the script if that specific line is not there.

> Rule is: that line will be always in line# 3. so it's stable position.

Example:

```
def great():
    print("Hi")
    print("Hello World")

great()
```

The previous code contain 5 lines.

line# 3 contain `print("Hello World")`

Now: How to edit the code and tell if line# 3 not containing that print so terminate the script.

Comment: You can `sys.exit()` to exit the script, but you have to clarify what exactly you want to check before exiting. Also, post code that is not working

Comment: I didn't get clear idea but try exit() function then based on condition if line 3 is not there

Comment: @PratikGandhi I'm aware about `sys.exit()` . I'm looking to terminate the script if the line itself is not there.

Comment: Also you can read about exiting the program: [python_exit](https://www.edureka.co/community/16988/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very naive solution reading the file before continuing with the script execution:

```
def great():
    print("Hi")
    print("Hello World")

with open("./test.py") as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()

if not lines[2].strip() == "print(\"Hello World\")":
    print("Exiting")
    exit(1)

great()
```

The following assumes that your script is called `test.py` and that there's absolutely nothing else on the line you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this with `autoreload` from IPython library.

Extract form their documentation:

```
In [1]: %load_ext autoreload

In [2]: %autoreload 2

In [3]: from foo import some_function

In [4]: some_function()
Out[4]: 42

In [5]: # open foo.py in an editor and change some_function to return 43

In [6]: some_function()
Out[6]: 43
```

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html